# Convert List<T> into json in flutter

Tags: android, json, dart, flutter

I have a list of option when the attribute is selected of a particular option then I save attribute object at the selected position of option in the list.
now I have an option list with their selected attribute object. My aim is to convert the options list into JSON object but when the attribute is not null. The Attribute object can be null in that case when a person has not chosen an attribute of an option.

```
class OptionAttribute{
 String _grouprowid;
 String _groupname;
 Attribute _selectedAttrObject

   Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'attribute': _selectedAttrObject,
  };
}

class Attribute{

  String _attributerowid;
  String _grouprowid;
  String _attributename;
  String _weight;

   Map<String, dynamic> toJsonAttr() => {
    'attrid': _attributerowid,
    'groupid': _grouprowid,
    'attrname': _attributename
  };

}
```

I want to convert below list into JSON object when the list does not have any null attribute.

```
List<OptionAttribute> opAtrrList=new List<OptionAttribute>();
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You need to convert each item individually

```
var json = jsonEncode(opAttrList.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList());
```

or pass an `toEncodable` function

```
var json = jsonEncode(opAttrList, toEncodable: (e) => e.toJsonAttr());
```

Comment: showing error of `Instance of 'MappedListIterable<OptionAttribute, Map<String, dynamic>>` where I'm doing wrong

Comment: `'attribute': _selectedAttrObject,` should be `'attribute': _selectedAttrObject.toJsonAttr(),`

Comment: now it is showing error `Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'Attribute'`

Comment: (unrelated to the errors you mentioned) You should name `toJson()` the same on all classes. For example there is no point in adding `Attr` to `toJson()`.

Comment: Gunter almost done,  but how can i handle if `attribute` is not selected in that case it is showing error **The method 'toJson' was called on null.**

Comment: Adding `?` might do `'attribute': _selectedAttrObject?.toJson(),` or if you want `'attribute': null` removed as well, use `Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _selectedAttrObject != null ? {
    'attribute': _selectedAttrObject,
  } : {};`

Comment: Glad to hear :)