# Flutter: How to convert a List to JSON

Tags: json, list, flutter

I am trying to convert a list to Json and sent this json to DB.

My list is as following

```
List<DeviceInfo> deviceInfoList = [];

class DeviceInfo {
  final String platform;
  final String deviceModel;
  final bool isPhysicalDevice;
  final String deviceId;
  final String imei;
  final String meid;
  final String platformVersion;
  final String projectVersion;
  final String projectCode;
  final String projectAppID;
  final String projectName;

  DeviceInfo(
      {this.platform,
      this.platformVersion,
      this.deviceModel,
      this.isPhysicalDevice,
      this.deviceId,
      this.imei,
      this.meid,
      this.projectVersion,
      this.projectCode,
      this.projectAppID,
      this.projectName});
}
```

My list contain String and boolean, I had go through [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55024549/flutter-json-encode-list) don't know how to Map string and bool in that map function.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Json Encode List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55024549/flutter-json-encode-list)

Comment: @luismiguelss My list contain string and Boolean, how can i map it to the function in the link you provided. Map<String,dynamic> toJson(){
    return {}}

Comment: You can still process the boolean as a String, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55058117/convert-listt-into-json-in-flutter)

Comment: Thank you so much @luismiguelss Got it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert List<T> into json in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55058117/convert-listt-into-json-in-flutter)

Answer (score 3):

```
Map<String,dynamic> toJson(){
    return {
      "name": this.name,
      "number": this.number,
      "surname": this.surname,
    };
  }

static List encondeToJson(List<DeviceInfo>list){
    List jsonList = List();
    list.map((item)=>
      jsonList.add(item.toJson())
    ).toList();
    return jsonList;
}

List jsonList = Device.encondeToJson(deviceInfoList);
print("jsonList: ${jsonList}");
```

Is the most short way that I remember.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of options that will help encoding and decoding from JSON: the [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) package is a great way to have the boilerplate serialize/deserialize code generated for you. There's examples of how to use this (and [built_value](https://pub.dev/packages/built_value), which is powerful, but more complicated to use) in the [Flutter samples repo](https://github.com/flutter/samples/tree/master/jsonexample).