# Flutter get all data from list into json

Tags: flutter, dart

I am saving data in a list now i need to post it in to my apis so i need to convert this in json but i am stuck how can i call all list of data

My code

```
class DiagCollection with ChangeNotifier {

  List<Items_other> otheritems = [];


  void addOthers(Items_other day) {
    otheritems.add(day);
    print(otheritems);
    notifyListeners();
  }
  void removeOthers(int index) {
    otheritems.removeAt(index);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class Items_other {
  String name;
  String comments;
  int id;
  Items_other({this.name, this.comments, this.id});
  
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'name': name,
    'comments': comments,
    'id': id,
  };
}
```

I am inserting data like this

```
  final collection = Provider.of<DiagCollection>(context);


   collection
      .addOthers(Items_other(
    name: "Allergies",
    id: otherAllergiesselect,
    comments: otherAllergiesselectText.text,
  ));
```

Now i need to get all addOthers List in json

Comment: Do you want to convert your list to json or you want to add this list to json as a field?

Comment: If you want to convert list into JSON then just use JSON.encode method. Try this and see if you are encountering any error

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you are trying to convert list of objects to json List.
If I got true, it is a duplicate of following repository. [convert List to jsons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55058117/convert-listt-into-json-in-flutter)
You can not convert your list to object. you need to apply it elementwise then convert to json.

```
var json = jsonEncode(yourlistofobject.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList());
```